# What does the Profile path field do in ADUC?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, roaming-profile

I noticed today that about 1/3 of our users have an empty field here in their ADUC properties 
[image]

The other 2/3 have "\\servername\profiles$\username". What I'm wondering is how it's possible that 33% of our users in this roaming profile environment, don't have roaming profiles. I checked that folder. For all the users with an empty field, they either have no roaming profile folder at all, or the one there hasn't been "Modified" in like 3 years.

Comment: It sounds like you already know what that field does? It enables a roaming profile for the user. I don’t understand why you would be asking how it’s possible some users wouldn’t have a roaming profile. If an admin doesn’t set the field, it isn’t set, and there is no roaming profile. I can’t tell you why the network admins did or didn’t do something.

Comment: ^^^ Ditto what Appleoddity said. A roaming profile isn't a requirement. Some users were set up for roaming profiles and some were not. Some were set up for roaming profiles in the past and now are not. Mystery solved.

Comment: Except according to the head Network Admin III, all users have a roaming profile. There isn't anyone who should be without one. First login of a new AD account on a domain computer is supposed to spawn one. If 1/3 of our users don't have roaming profiles, why aren't we seeing dozens of calls from people wondering where documents and settings changes have disappeared each morning?